# change the background color of my header dynamically with js

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I was building a website and I want to change background color of my header when its reach to a certain id , but I'm newbie at JavaScript so what do you think about it , what's the best way to do it.

Comment: "_when its reach to a certain id_" Does the header have a dynamic id too? Or it's sticky, and you want to change the color when user has scrolled to a specific element on the page?

Comment: post what you have done so far

Comment: Please show us some code. You can create code examples for us on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pen) or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for example and post the URL here.